# Extract (multiple) TeX environement to csv with python script

Tags: python, latex

My first question in python, pls be kind :)

**Question**

How do I handle the extraction of the `.tex` file (as described below) to a flat csv (with format below) ?

**Context**

I created all my MCQ in LaTeX. However exams are now 100% online... (sigh)

My LaTeX file has the basic following format

```
\documentclass[12pt]{exam}
​
\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
 \question What is the answer ? 
 \begin{oneparchoices}
 \choice 75
 \choice 80
 \CorrectChoice 85
 \choice None of the above
 \end{oneparchoices}
\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I need now to provide a csv where the questions of the MCQ above would be displayed like (**Inc**orrect,**Cor**rect, just to be clear

`question,answer1,Cor/Inc,answer2,Cor/Inc,answer3,Cor/Inc ,answer4,Cor/Inc,answer5,Cor/Inc`

And it would render like

`What is the answer ?,Inc,70,Inc,75,Inc,80,Inc,85,Cor,None of the above,Inc`

Each line would obviously be a new question.

**What could correspond so far**

I see the principle for environment between `\begin` and `\end` thanks to [Extract figures from latex file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11054008/extract-figures-from-latex-file)

```
infile = open('MCQ.tex', 'r')
outfile = open('FlattenMCQ.csv', 'w')
extract_block = False
for line in infile:
    if 'begin{questions}' in line:
        extract_block = True
    if extract_block:
        outfile.write(line)
    if 'end{questions}' in line:
        extract_block = False
        outfile.write("------------------------------------------\n\n")

infile.close()
outfile.close()
```

**Where I am stuck**
The recurisivity to test first `\begin{questions}` then `\question` then  `\begin{oneparchoices}` then `\choice` or  `\CorrectChoice`

Comment: Well, it is about Compilation Principle's front end. You may can learn it in one day if you can. To be honset, it is hard to match/deal with. In C, I know that yacc/lex tools is helpful to write a front end quickly.

Comment: @PeterlitsZo ok, and what do i do from there ? :)

Comment: I hope that this can help you: http://www.stack.nl/~marcov/compiler.pdf, you only need to build a lexer to get a token stream, and parse it to AST, then convert it to csv.

Comment: Or those books may help you: https://github.com/EbookFoundation/free-programming-books/blob/master/free-programming-books.md#compiler-design

Comment: @PeterlitsZo thank you. My question was more a call for help :) I won't have time to dig into all these books before I can provide my exam in the new format for the end of the semester.

Comment: well, wait for me...